# parse javascript via simple html dom

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Is there any way to return URL in this code via SIMPLE HTML DOM:

```
<div class="film">
<script type="text/javascript">

            jwplayer("myElement").setup({
                file: "http://images.example.com/system.mp4",
                image: "",
                width: 500
            });
</script>
</div>
```

I want to have this URL:

```
http://images.example.com/system.mp4
```

Comment: No. Javascript is not HTML, and does therefore not end up in a nice DOM structure. The content of the JS tag is seen as, ah, one HTML tag.

Comment: You can access the (JS code) text content of a script tag: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9333914/get-content-inside-script-as-text - just do a regex search on that text.