# Is it possible to programmatically access the contents of external scripts from an HTML script tag?

Tags: javascript, html

Lets say I am using the `turndown` Javascript package:

https://github.com/mixmark-io/turndown

and loading it this way in my HTML:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/turndown/dist/turndown.js"></script>
```

This loads the following:

[image]

and makes `TurnDown` service available to be used as such:

```
var turndownService = new TurndownService({ headingStyle: 'atx', emDelimiter : '*' });
```

Is it possible to programmatically access the contents of such external scripts which has been loaded by the above `script` tag? Aka, is it possible to get the following:

```
var TurndownService = (function () {
  'use strict';

  function extend (destination) { ........

  .....

  return TurndownService;

}());
```

NOTE that I am asking for external scripts. I already know I can get contents of my own script by assigning the tag an id and then using `innerHTML` on it as such:

[Get content inside script as text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9333914/get-content-inside-script-as-text)

The reason I need to do this is that I want to pass these third party scripts to a WebView in iOS using webkit handlers.

Comment: Please be clear about you want: it is *absolutely* possible to see the contents of a 3rd party script in the devtools "sources" tab. If you want *programmatic* access to the contents it's still possible, although more laborious.

Comment: @JaredSmith I have clarified my question.

Comment: @Yogi I need to pass these scripts to a WebView using webkit handlers.

Comment: You can iterate through `document.scripts` until you find the one with the `src` attribute that matches what you want and grab the `innerHTML`.

Comment: @JaredSmith `innerHTML` doesn't seem to work for external script. It's empty. That's the problem.

Comment: No, you cannot access the source of the script unless you re-fetch the script.

Comment: @sudoExclamationExclamation The issue is that JS doesn't preserve the original text after parsing it, so even if you could access it, you'd be reading objects and references, rather than a string containing `var ... =`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! There is a `document.scripts` property that contains all scripts loaded on a page. However, external scripts loaded with `src` attribute won't have `innerHTML` or `textContent`, so we will have to fetch it again.

In your case, you can get the contents like this:

```js
const desiredUrl = "https://unpkg.com/turndown/dist/turndown.js"
const script = [...document.scripts].find(script => script.src === desiredUrl)

const url = script.src
const source = fetch(url).then(res => res.text()).then(source => {
  console.log(source.slice(0, 200)) // truncated not to spam console
})
```

Comment: I was aware of this workaround but it seems to require refetching of an already loaded script. I was wondering if there's a way to not need that?

Comment: If you have access to devtools, for example using Puppeteer, there are ways to do it. But not as a normal JavaScript running in the browser. Might I ask why it's important not to re-fetch it? It's probably in the cache already, so performance hit should be minimal.

Comment: It's not a massive deal. I was just wondering if there's a way which doesn't need it. Like a simple `innerHTML` sort of thing. But if not possible, I will accept this workaround.